# codeigniter multi apps using 1 system, 1 database

Tags: codeigniter, installation

i would like to achieve the following file structure with codeigniter:

these folders above www
    `ci/system/...`
    `ci/application/site_1/config/config.php`
    `ci/application/site_2/config/config.php`

these folders under www
    `www/site_1/index.php`
    `www/site_2/index.php`

Both sites are using the same codeigniter system file.
Both sites are having the same php code.
Bot sites are using different set of mysql tables as I have only 1 mysql database and i intend to use table prefix to differentiate them. eg.

site1_login
site1_register

site2_login
site2_register

Any advise on how to configure the index.php file and config.php file, thanks.

Comment: Are the two sites `www/site_1` & `www/site_2` virtual directories, or are they all under the same domain name? I.E. do you access them via `http://mysite.com/site_1` & `http://mysite.com/site_2` or do they have their own domain names?

Comment: Site 1 & Site 2 are under the same domain name.

Comment: As well as the above you'll need to also set up `.htaccess` files for each site too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea of application folder being separate to system folder in CodeIgniter is that you can have  different applications with same system folder. I would be structuring it as follows:

```
/base/system
/base/application_1
/base/application_2
/base/webroot/site_1/index.php
/base/webroot/site_2/index.php
```

Then change to 2 index.php files to point to the relevant `system` and `application` folders. In both application folders, I would be pointing to the same DB details as well.

Comment: That was what i've written above. I can open the index page for both sites but i failed to open a hyperlink(<a href="login">) to the login page in both the index page. It gives me error message: Internal Server Error. Which part had i miss out?